# Is there a Jewish equivalent of "Pray as if everything depended on God; act as if everything depended on you."?

Tags: tefilla, miracle

A popular phrase, frequently and wrongly attributed to the Talmud, is "Pray as if everything depended on God; act as if everything depended on you."

I am trying to find out if there is anything in our Sources along those lines.  The closest I could find comes from Radak (13th-century Spain) commenting on Genesis 12:10:

> The promises by God are based on man having taken every reasonable precaution not to require a miracle to save him from danger. When one is aware that one finds oneself in a situation where danger to one’s life is likely, one must first take every precaution at one’s disposal to counter such danger. Our Sages [Pesachim 64b] have told us that it is inadmissible to sit ... waiting for God to perform a miracle to save one’s life. They base this advice on the verse in Torah:
> לֹ֣א תְנַסּ֔וּ אֶת־יְהוָ֖ה אֱלֹהֵיכֶ֑ם
> Do not try the Lord your God. [Deut. 6:16]
> which means “do not put God in a position of having to perform a miracle for you.” ... When righteous people face danger in carrying out what they know to be God’s will, they must not leave matters to miracles.

In other words, don't rely on miracles.  Anything closer than that in the Sources?

Comment: [A quick Google search reveals](https://www.catholic.com/magazine/online-edition/st-ignatius-said-what) that the quote is actually attributed to either St. Augustine or St. Ignatius in Catholicism.

Comment: Apparently this is quoted by a lot of Reform/Progressive/Liberal Jews (not all appear to be aware that it's Christian). One added [here](https://wupj.org/library/the-weekly-portion/1216/torah-from-around-the-world-346/): "Rabbi Moshe Leib of Sassov, boldly declared: “If someone comes to you and asks your help, you shall not turn him away with pious words saying: ‘Have faith; God will help you!’ You shall act as if there were no God, as if there were only one person in all the world who could help this needy individual – only you, yourself.” (Martin Buber: Tales of the Hasidim, p. 440)".

Comment: This statement goes counter to everything I ever read on the topic of bitachon.

Comment: @N.T. That depends on how you interpret the words 'act as if', doesn't it?

Comment: @Harel13 I believe the same idea is also quoted in the name of one of the baalei mussar, maybe R. Yisroel Salanter

Comment: @Harel13: First someone says something they read somewhere. Then people start assigning it to random authorities. Then people assume it must be true because they heard it in the name of so many authorities. Then they act shocked when you question it. The point is, every Jewish authority agrees that bitachon must reach the level of action for it to mean something.

Comment: Actually @N.T. from the start it didn't sound too far off from Rambam says about hashgacha pratit, so there's that...

Comment: Which Rambam? You don't mean the one in Moreh Nevuchim where he discusses hashgacha for animals, I hope.